# JAR creation failed using Upload Function to AWS Lambda in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, aws-lambda

While using the AWS Toolkit for Eclipse, an error has been encountered when attempting to upload a Lambda function; the error is that that JAR creation failed.  It is a simple "Hello World" application that was created to ensure that the environment is working; it follows the AWS tutorial: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/toolkit-for-eclipse/v1/user-guide/lambda-tutorial.html

The "Maven Build..." works fine to create the JAR without any error; following the steps in https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/lambda/latest/dg/java-create-jar-pkg-maven-and-eclipse.html.

Eclipse is being run on a Mac and the JRE is Amazon Corretto 11 (11.0.4).

Any suggestions?

Here are the details of the errors:

```
Failed to upload project to Lambda
m.amazonaws.eclipse.core.exceptions.AwsActionException
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:115)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsJobWizard$1.run(AbstractAwsJobWizard.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.util.UploadFunctionUtil.performFunctionUpload(UploadFunctionUtil.java:82)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:111)


Unable to export project [testproject] to jar file
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: JAR creation failed. See details for additional information.
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.jarpackager.JarFileExportOperation.singleRun(JarFileExportOperation.java:1006)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.jarpackager.JarFileExportOperation.execute(JarFileExportOperation.java:996)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.lambda$0(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2322)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.WorkspaceModifyOperation.run(WorkspaceModifyOperation.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.util.FunctionJarExportHelper.exportProjectToJarFile(FunctionJarExportHelper.java:78)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.util.UploadFunctionUtil.performFunctionUpload(UploadFunctionUtil.java:68)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.lambda.upload.wizard.UploadFunctionWizard.doFinish(UploadFunctionWizard.java:111)
    at com.amazonaws.eclipse.core.plugin.AbstractAwsJobWizard$1.run(AbstractAwsJobWizard.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

Comment: I just used the AWS console to upload the JAR. Thanks for the down vote!

Comment: Thanks for asking this question.  I got similar errors when trying to create a Java AWS lambda, and followed the instructions on the link you provided.  I was finally successful in uploading my jar to S3, and running the tests from inside AWS.